# Just bought house with hairline diagonal crack from window

Tags: crack, new-home

[image]

We just bought our house at the end of November here in Wisconsin. So weather is changing. Noticed this crack by the window. House is from 60s I believe. Should I be concerned? Or could this be from tempture change. This does stem from a large corner window with two windows near it too.

Comment: At least check the basement/slab for any signs of recent (or long term) water damage or heaving. Make sure downspouts are moving water away from the foundation. Is there 8' of snow on the roof? If all of these are no, just watch it, and follow eagles answer, Time to enjoy home ownership, congrats!

Comment: Thanks! There has been no real heavy snow fall. And no downspouts are on that side.

Answer (score 2):

Probably just the house settling - could be due to:

- Underlying soil conditions causing the house to rise or fall
- Changes in seasonal humidity causing the window casing to shrink
- Perhaps you didn't notice it until it got dark and cold so you're inside more
- Moving in: if the house was empty, then filled with all your belongings, it can actually cause the house to settle.  Happened to my parents' house.

Probably not a serious structural issue (IANAL). If you patch it, make sure to use some reinforcing mesh to keep it from just cracking again.

Perhaps [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/why-does-the-plaster-crack-beneath-the-window-sill/1059#1059) might also help.

Comment: Thanks! There was a 10 degree temperature drop around when we moved in so that makes sense.

Comment: It would make sense to accept the answer then, & Iron would probably appreciate it :)